# Joomla "can't open file" Error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, caching, joomla

I am having the strangest error come up on a site that I am working on. For a while we have had the site in admin only view so we could work on things without any users logging in. Was fine during this phase.

Today we opened up the site to a handful of people to sign up and test the site out. As people started coming in however, every user was getting this error:

"can't open file" with a white screen

The error first pops up when the user tries to register and gets to the final page. This is the part that is supposed to tell the user that a email confirmation link has been sent to them.

Once this error pops up, the error will continue to display for all pages until they clear their cache.

**Changes that were done:**

1: Prior to opening the site up, the .htaccess was edited to prompt a initial login box (this was done to prevent others from accessing the site while we were moving to a 'beta' phase). I also added a .htpasswd file that contained the details for the users to enter to get to the site. I have tried to delete this edit thinking that it was this acting up, but did not work, error was still displaying.

2: Checking and repairing the joomla session table within the database - my thoughts were that perhaps it was a session issue since it was triggered when the user went to sign up and complete the registration process. This did not work.

3: One of the components that we were using needed a custom edit to the session.php file.  "/libraries/joomla/session/session.php" - I reverted this file back to the original, however the error still comes up. Did this, thinking it was session related as the point above)

4: I cleared all cache and purged all expired cache, this had no effect. I also cleared all cache as I did the previous 3 items as well.

So now I am completely stumped on how to go ahead and get this working correct. The error that displays is VERY vague and leaves no information other than it 'can't open file'

Joomla Version: Joomla! 3.4.8 Stable

PHP Version: 5.6.16

Web Server: LiteSpeed

Community Component: EasySocial

Subscription Component: PayPlans

Comment: I think this question would suit better on the Joomla forum: http://forum.joomla.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've sorted this now I think. Looking in the logs one of the site plugins was using the ftp layer to open a file which had been created directly by Apache, and so the permissions didn't allow it.
I've change the permissions now and the error condition seems to have gone.